# model class attribute string length as nvarchar max

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I assign ms sql server data type `nvarchar max` length in model class attribute.
Suppose I have one attribute, StudentName

```
[Required]
[MinLength(5)]
[MaxLength(200)]
public string StudentName { get; set; }
```

How can I make StudentName datatype as nvarchar max?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to limit the value of your string `MaxLength (200)` why use `MaxLength`? You just need to remove the `MaxLength(200)` to change your model to `nvarchar max`.

If you want to use a limit of 200 characters only on your controller and views, it is better to use `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Column()` attribute, which you can use to specify exact **SQL Server** data type. for example:

```
[MaxLength(200)]
[Column(TypeName="nvarchar(max)")]
public string StudentName { get; set; }
```

> Note: `MaxLength` attribute will be overridden by the **`Column`** attribute, but in **model binding** `StudentName` would validated by its `MaxLength` attribute.

And if you prefer, you can achieve this using **Fluent API** in this way:

```
 builder.Property(x => x.StudentName)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
                .IsRequired();
```

*By the way, it is not practical to filter user input with `MaxLength`, but in database set the field type `nvarchar(max)`.*